# Refresh page after AJAX request in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQueryMobile page anatomy at index.html:

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
```

I'm interested in loading the other pages (that don't have this anatomy) to `data-role="content"` through AJAX in order to use the same header and footer accross all the pages.

The code bellow works fine but doesn't refresh the elements with jQueryMobile styles.

```
$( 'div:jqmData(role="content")' ).load( 'pages/home.html' );
```

Comment: is `pages/home.html` a full page with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: No, contains only the specific HTML of the page.

Comment: the styles of `pages/home.html` are different and not contain in the ones of `index.html`? AFAIK, putting _all_ the css in `index.html` would be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is tell the jQuery Framework to initialize the new widgets:

```
$( '.ui-content' ).load( 'pages/home.html', function () { $(this).trigger('create') });
```

Also, if all you want is a persistent header/footer then you should check-out just that feature that jQuery Mobile has: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-b.html

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VMhz4/1/

## Update

You can dynamically add `data-role="button"` to links like this if you need:

```
$( '.ui-content' ).load( 'pages/home.html', function () {

    //after the AJAX request has resolved and the HTML has been added to the DOM, this will run

    //find all the links that were just added to the DOM and add the `data-role="button"` attribute to each,
    //then end the current selection (returning to `$(this)`) and initialize all widgets
    $(this).find('a').attr('data-role', 'button').end().trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: It does in fact work (here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VMhz4/1/). You'll have to be more specific with how it doesn't work. What error(s) do you get? Are you adding the necessary `data-role` attributes to elements? What does the code of `pages/home.html` look like?

Comment: Your example is working because it's appending elements and not loading them from another html file. The code of home.html contains a button without data-roles.

Comment: Well, they need `data-role="button"` hard-coded on them or you have to add it via JS because jQuery Mobile doesn't know to initialize the content unless you tell it what kind of content it is. See the **update** to my answer for a way to automatically add the proper `data-attributes` to elements just before initializing them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it works fine. But when I mentioned that home.html only contains a button was for tests purpose, actually that file can contain a variable number of jQueryMobile elements and initialize them all sounds a bit slow. Is there any other approach you recommend?

Comment: I've solved the problem using $( 'div:jqmData(role=content)' ).load( 'pages/home.html', function(){ $( this ).trigger( 'create' ); } );

Comment: That's the same code as the **update** in my answer. Simply remove the `.find('a').attr('data-role', 'button').end()` and the only difference is the selector which selects the same thing(s).

Comment: Exactly, but using  $( this ).trigger( 'create' ); instead of $(this).find('a').attr('data-role', 'button').end().trigger('create'); initializes all jQuery Mobile elements.

Comment: Could you please update your answer so that I can mark it as accepted? Between, how to you format your code on comments? :)

Comment: It's updated, `.find('a').attr('data-role', 'button').end()` finds the link elements, then adds an attribute to them, and finally it ends the current selection, returning to the `$(this)` selection, so even though it does a bit more as well, it does do the same thing as `$(this).trigger('create')`. To add code formatting in a comment use back-ticks (`, generally found top-left of the keyboard on the same key as tilde).